# Formatting MySQL Query Data Into Custom Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following data being returned from my database query:

```
+---------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-------+
| district_name | school_id | school_name      | section      | score |
+---------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-------+
| My ISD        |        11 | My First School  | English      |    20 |
| My ISD        |        11 | My First School  | Math         |    23 |
| My ISD        |        11 | My First School  | Reading      |    24 |
| My ISD        |        11 | My First School  | Science      |    23 |
| My ISD        |        12 | My Second School | English      |    11 |
| My ISD        |        12 | My Second School | Math         |    19 |
| My ISD        |        12 | My Second School | Reading      |    22 |
| My ISD        |        12 | My Second School | Science      |    26 |
+---------------+-----------+------------------+--------------+-------+
```

I need to put this data into an array to easily output a table of scores by school:

```
School                  English  Math  Reading Science
-------------------------------------------------------
My First School         20       23    24      23
My Second School        11       19    22      26
```

I'm having trouble formatting this data into an array that accomplishes this. The ideal structure would be:

```
array(
  $schoolName => array(
    'results' => array(
       'section' => $section_name
       'score' => $score
    ),
  ),
);
```

I've tried several approaches but can't get them to work correctly.

Comment: What do you mean you can't get them to work correctly? What goes wrong? Are there errors? Data is lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //you can define the query, right?
    $array[$row['school_name']]['results'][$row['section']] = $row['score'];
}
```

Although I don't support the way you have your database set up, I'm not going to give you a lecture on it. I'd assume this is a school project or something.

Comment: The data structure above is not the structure of my DB. It's the data being returned via my query.

Comment: Not sure what my problem is... ginormous brain fart... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table_rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
  $school_name = $row['school_name'];
  $table_rows[$school_name]['results'][$row['section']] = $row['score'];
  // adding the other stuff to $table_rows...
}
```

I hope this helps.